# Upload file in PHP?

Tags: php, upload

When I upload an image file to the host, why the file repeat filename extension again ? I check the filename in the host is like `test.jpg.jpg`

Here is the code:

```php
$uploadPath = "../../upload/Image/";

$handle = new Upload($_FILES['pic'], 'zh_TW');    

if($handle->uploaded){
    $pic=$_FILES['pic']['name'];
    if($pic != ''){
        $filename = $pic;
    }
    else{
        $microSecond = microtime();
        $filename = substr($microSecond, 11, 20).substr($microSecond, 2, 8);
    }                

    $handle->file_new_name_body     = $filename;
    $handle->image_resize           = true;
    $handle->image_ratio_y          = true;
    $handle->image_x                = 212;
    $handle->image_ratio_fill       = true;
    $handle->allowed                = array('image/*');
    $handle->file_overwrite         = true;
    $handle->process($uploadPath);
    if($handle->processed){ 
        $handle->file_dst_name = $filename;
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>";
        echo "alert('$handle->error');";
        echo "history.back();";
        echo "</script>";
        die;
    }
}
else{
    $filename = $_POST['currentPic'];
}
```

Comment: Please post code for Upload class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on your conditions. you can just get the name onle part by explode function.

```
if($handle->uploaded){
    $pic=$_FILES['pic']['name'];
    if($pic != ''){
        //$filename = $pic;
        $filename = explode(".",$pic)[0];
    }
    else{
        $microSecond = microtime();
        $filename = substr($microSecond, 11, 20).substr($microSecond, 2, 8);
    }
```

This is so you dont need to modify your class, also if you modify your class you will get trouble on the "ELSE" side of your condition that will cause additional spending time where to get the extension.